# Four children with superpowers, possible confrontation with pirates on a ship

Tags: story-identification, novel

I remember very few details of the book I am looking for, but here goes:

- The story in question was a full length book.
- I'm pretty sure it was the first book in a series; I never read anything other than the one book though.
- It was a fantasy book.
- I would say the target audience was young adult.
- I read the book in 2011. I don't think it was an old book at the time (i.e probably written in the 2000s, rather than, say, the 1980s).
- I believe I read it in a soft-cover volume; I do not recall the cover art.
- I read the book in English, and that was the original language of publication.
- The main characters were a group of children, I believe four in all.
- They were a mixture of boys and girls, probably two and two.
- The children had some form of superpower. I believe one of the girls was very strong, one of the boys was very fast, (though it might have been that the girl was strong *and* fast) and one of the boys was very smart.
- I have some vague recollection that the strong girl's name started with "M"; she may have been the unofficial leader of the group (and possibly the oldest).
- The children were brought together by some group to stop some badguys.
- I think there might have been other people with superpowers as well, and these four children were chosen out of a larger group.
- I think one of the boys was very young, and there might have been some controversy about whether to include him on the team.
- I think there was some point in the story where the strong girl visited the young boy's house, possibly secretly.
- I believe there was some confrontation on a ship, perhaps involving pirates.
- There may have been a point where the strong girl tied up one or two badguys.

I know this is not much to go on....

Comment: Any chance this is a corruption of some details of the Maximum Ride series? I don't think it's super likely, but wanted to put it out there.

Comment: @Kitkat It doesn’t seem so.

Comment: Whoever the author was, they seem to have read the Power Pack comics in the '80s. Too many elements match up. I don't believe it was ever truly novelized, just comics and graphic novels.